# Preloading HTML5 video for smooth AJAX page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, video

### Inquiry

I am creating smooth transitions between pages via jQuery's `.fade()` effect. The second page (*page2.html*) contains HTML5 video elements (either *.webm* or *.mp4* depending on the browser). How can I preload these movies prior to `page2.html` loading in order to eliminate the brief flash/blip indicating the location of the video element itself? (You know, the greyish screen showing precisely where the player is.)

To be clear, I am ***not*** asking how to eliminate the white flash between page loads; I simply want to have the video player ready and movies completely loaded before ever displaying *page2.html* itself.

### Code Examples

**AJAX fade transitioning:**

```
$('#wrapper').fadeOut(2500, function() {
  $(this).load('page2.html', function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(2500);
  });
});
```

**HTML5 video from page2.html**

```
<video id="example" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
  <source src="video/example.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="video/example.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: It might be easier to use a timeout before fading in.

Comment: Perhaps, but how do you guarantee the video is loaded with a timeout? canPlayThrough?

Comment: Fading in on `canPlayThrough` is best option.

Comment: Interesting solution. I'll give it a go and report back. You should submit as an answer. :-)

Comment: Frankly, your the one that came up with the solutions :) If you got it to work just post your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bart.

```
var loaded = false;

//If the video is loaded...
example.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {

  //Make sure it only fires once
  if (loaded == false) {
    loaded = true;

    //Fade in the content
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn(2500);

  }
});
```